# Android - View method to check if activity is going to be minimized

Tags: android

I am wondering if there is any way to know, from inside a class that extends the View class method, if the activity, in which the view is present, is going to be minimized and if there is a way to call some methods (again from inside that class that extends the View class) before the activity minimizes.

I already tried onPause() from the Activity class but that`s not what I need. I need something that is called from within the View class before the activity is paused/minimized.

**Edit:**

In my app I am forcing the soft input to appear, but on home button press (activity minimization) the soft input remains there. The soft input method can't be changed to SHOW_IMPLICIT. Also as I've read it's considered malicious to override the home button.
Anyway, I can not make use of the Activity methods and I need something from inside the View that is called when the minimization takes place so I could override it and add the hideSoftInput call to it.

Comment: Are you sure that you really want to make this kind of treatment in a View component? Seems clear to me that you need to handle lifecycle in this specific use, why not a fragment then?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. I already tried overriding onWindowVisibilityChanged() but as it seems the home button task is executed faster.